# Taking Screen shots on specific error page in selenium web driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

My scenario is, I'm getting same error page on many of my button clicks on the site.
I want to take screenshots, of this same error page, with reference on which link of the site this error page occured. 
So I want screenshot whenever this error page occurs on any click.
Can you suggest me how to write the function for this and how to call that function in some other function in selenium Webdriver.
Please share some code sample for that.

**As of currently, I'm writing it only as :**

```
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);  FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("D:\\Home\\Ruchi\\failure.png"));
```

But in this I need to write these lines of code after every failure occurrence.

Comment: Please provide your lines of code where you want to use this.

Comment: I have some of example codes/scenario which might helps you. Tell me If you need this.

Comment: SWNfindElement1("ctl00_CenterCPH_btnUpload","upload bulk vendors");
     File scrFile1 = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);  
     FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile1, new File("D:\\Home\\Ruchi\\failure(upload bulk vendors).png"));  like in this code here after this button click I'm getting error page, so similarly there are many links and button, so I want to get screenshot for each of this event,with different png file name and which event occured.

Comment: You can get my mail from my profile and send your steps. Then I can say or give answer.

Comment: @Sagar007 please share your answer with the community - and use comments/chat to discuss - rather than taking it offline. We all want to see.

Comment: @AndrewRegan I have many scenarios in my mind that can solve this problem differently. So which is best is depends on questioner situation. That is why I have asked for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use try and catch block

```
try{
  // Put your script here
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
            File scrn=((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

            // extracting date for folder name.
            SimpleDateFormat sdfDate1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");//dd/MM/yyyy
            Date now1 = new Date();
            String strDate1 = sdfDate1.format(now1);

            // extracting date and time for snapshot file
            SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss");//dd/MM/yyyy
            Date now = new Date();
            String strDate = sdfDate.format(now);

            String filefolder="./Snap/"+strDate1+"/";  // create a folder as snap in  your project directory

            // Creating folders and files
            File f = new File(filefolder+strDate+".jpeg");

            FileUtils.copyFile(scrn, new File(f.getPath()));
}
```

If your script fails then the program jumps to catch block and then code will take screen shot for you

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: But over here the png file will get overrided on each instance the error is generated, I want to get the screenshots with different file name and where it has occured.

Comment: Exactly I know tht.. for that you can use time and date .. I have updated my answer .. It will save pic accroding to date .. time and sec

Comment: this is usefull, thanks alot. But I also want on which page or link is the exception occuring

Comment: Jsut add this code in my code System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());

Comment: It will give you the current page on which except had been occur